# How to set multi controller's package base to my SwaggerConfiguration?

Tags: java, swagger, springfox

My dependency....

```
<!-- SPRING BOOT -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My problem happen when i tried to use in swagger two packages base. Below you can see what i mean with package base and above you can see my dependency. My code that i tried to use two package base are more below.

```
aPackageBase: com.companyx
bPackageBase: br.com.companyz
```

---

### Things that I cannot do

- I cannot change the package base because they are huge APIs.
- I have more then 10 APIs that follow that 2 package base.
- I would like to use `aPackageBase` and `bPackageBase`.

---

### Current code, that is not working...

```
...
String aPackageBase = "com.companyx";
String bPackageBase = "br.com.companyz";

Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30).select() //
    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(aPackageBase) //
        .and(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(bPackageBase))) // That doesn't work :(....
        .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build()

...
```

---

### What would like to have...

I just want to use **both packages base**. I am not trying to change the at runtime, of course I can change it at runtime and use only `one packageBase`, but I am tired to change it for each API. If I can have `aPackageBase` and `bPackageBase` it will save my life. haaha.

---

Note: I don't think I need show more about my SwaggerConfiguration because my problem is only in that part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change your `Docket` bean definition a little bit.

```
Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30)
    .select() //
    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(aPackageBase) //
        .or(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(bPackageBase))) // use or here, not and
    .paths(PathSelectors.any())
    .build();
```

`RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(...)` returns a `java.util.function.Predicate` object.

`Predicate#and` requires both condition to be true, which is not, since any API will exist in one of the packages only. Hence `Predicate#or`.

Answer (score 2):

[Pratapi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63916742/4405757) is the right one. But if you are using an older version of springfox, the `basePackage` returns a Google Guava predicate [(link)](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/2.7.0/springfox/documentation/builders/RequestHandlerSelectors.html#basePackage(java.lang.String)).

Note that the Google Guava predicate extends the Java predicate and the `or` method is not overriden in the Guava Predicate. Hence, calling `or` will return a Java predicate. You can use a method reference (or a lambda expression) to pass a Guava predicate to the `apis` method.

```
//A java.util.function.Predicate
Predicate<RequestHandler> predicate = RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(aPackageBase)
          .or(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(bPackageBase));

return docket.select()
           .apis(predicate::test) //.apis(r -> p1.test(r))
           ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet worked for me for swagger2:

```
List<Predicate<RequestHandler>> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
predicateList.add(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(com.sample.one));
predicateList.add(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(com.sample.two));

Docket d = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(Predicates.or(predicateList))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build().forCodeGeneration(true)
                .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(oAuthSecurityScheme()));
```